# How to upload file in a target folder with php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, file-upload

I am new to PHP and learning it!

I  have created a simple database on my localhost name 'submitpaper'

Then I have created a table name 'upload_file' having two fields (file1, file2) both are (VARCHAR 255) 

I am having problem in saving files to target folder 'testupload'

**Kindly Check and Review My PHP Script And HTML**

**PHP Script**

```
<?php   
//This is the directory where files will be saved  
$target = "testupload/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form  
$file1=($_FILES['file1']['name']);
$file2=($_FILES['file2']['name']);

// Connects to your Database  
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
//Writes the information to the database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `upload_file` VALUES ('$file1', '$file2')") ;

//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target))  {
//Tells you if its all ok  
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). "has been uploaded,        and your information has been added to the directory";  }
else {   
//Gives and error if its not  echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";      }

?>
```

**HTML FILE CODE**

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
File1:<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
File2:<input type="file" name="file2" id="file2">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: is the target folder already created? If not you need to create it first , either manually or by php script.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: i have created target folder where the PHP file exists!
ERROR not showing only PHP script is displayed after clicking 'submit' button

Comment: if the PHP script is being displayed, then there is a high probability that you are not running the script on a server. You need a server(install wamp if windows, lamp if linux) to run php scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the file name incorrectly in `$_FILES['file']['name']`. You have to use like `$_FILES['nameoffile']['name']` where nameoffile is the name of the file you have given for the file input field. ie as,

```
$_FILES['file1']['name']
```

CODE:

```
$target = "testupload/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['file1']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code may useful for you.

```
$target = "Admin/upload/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']); 
$pic=($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']); 
//Writes the photo to the server 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{ 
    //Tells you if its all ok 
    //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
} 
else 
{ 
    //Gives and error if its not 
    //echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
}
```

**Before that you have to Read and Write permission for the file upload path folder.**

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to upload files

```
if(isset($_FILES['img']) && $_FILES['img']['error'] == 0)
      {
          $origin=$_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
          $destination='img/new_name-'.$id.'.jpg';
          move_uploaded_file($origin,$destination);
      }
```

I hope you find it useful

If you want to upload them simultaneously this is how the documentation says to do it

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
```

If you are going to upload them with the original name of the photo, I recommend that you rename them because it can cause problems if you upload two photos with the same name

I have never tried uploading several files simultaneously, maybe you should try uploading them separately